# Is the FX send on a Behringer 1202 mixer mono or stereo

Tags: behringer

That's it, really. I'm trying to set up a mix-minus for recording Skype calls with a Behringer 1202FX, using a UCA 202 to go in and out of the Skyping computer, and wondering whether the FX Send is mono or stereo.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the downloading the manual?

Comment: @ArnoudTraa - I did download the manual and while I could make a pretty good deduction from it, it was less than 100% clear what it was doing if you aren't particularly familiar with sound boards, so I'm not to surprised that jcherfas felt the need to ask.

Comment: Of course, I only asked if he downloaded the manual. He/She didn't include that in his question. And I think it's great that you're helping out, but checking the manual is nr. 1 on the list before you ask questions, imho

Comment: @ArnoudTraa - agreed, and my apologies if you were honestly suggesting it.  Typed language is always hard to understand tone and some people take a nasty tone when they think something is too easy to find.  I just wanted to make sure that jcherfas didn't feel like it was being suggested that it was a stupid question since the manual wasn't clear.

Comment: none taken, it's easy to misunderstand and it has happened before. it's great that you helped him out!

Comment: @jayjennings: Apologies if you feel a question about a tool often used in sound design was off topic. Could you perhaps suggest another Stack Exchange site where it might have been more appropriate?

Comment: @jcherfas, no need to apologize! While the Beringer may or may not be a tool used for sound design, your question doesn't relate to sound design at all. As a moderator, it's my job to keep all questions and comments focused on that craft. I suggest you find a board that deals specifically with sound boards, signal flow, etc. Perhaps GearSlutz? Sorry I can't suggest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the manual, it does appear to be stereo.  It isn't 100% clear, but it is a TRS connector and does not have insert functionality from the description and expects a stereo input to be used as the return.

Comment: I had read the small manual that is supplied with the mixer, and while I agree that it implies stereo -- "Once an effects mix is created, the processed signal can then be routed from the effects device outputs back into a stereo input." -- it isn't clear. And the diagram shows a TRS only for the headphones. Hence the question, so thanks for that.  Is there another, more detailed manual? I couldn't find one at Behringer.

Comment: Ah ok, you didn't state in your question that you'd already read the manual. On topic: Behringer actually visits and responds to this forum/site, search on behringer and you may find a user that works for them.

Comment: @jcherfas - that was the only manual I could find, but given that it is TRS and there is no description of insert functionality, there is no other reason I can think of why you would use a TRS jack if not stereo.